# Meaning of pointer operator in the layer function header in Caffe source code

Tags: c++, pointers

While reading the source code of Caffe, I've been wondering about the meaning of the pointer operator (*) in this use. What does `vector<Blob<Dtype>*>` mean, in particular?

```
void ConvolutionLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
```

Answer (score 3):

`Blob` is a template with type `Dtype` and so `Blob<Dtype>*` is a pointer to a `Blob<Dtype>`.

Therefore `vector<Blob<Dtype>*>` is a vector of pointers to `Blob<Dtpye>` objects.